# Using a lot of service classes in a domain model is a sign of what

Tags: design-patterns, domain-driven-design

I have recently tried practicing DDD and i found my self going towards lots of domain model objects that are pure data structures with no behavior and lots of services in the domain model and i would like to know if this is a sign of bad design, influence of architecture  (Entity Framework) on my design or using the wrong technique to develop this kind of application, i think it is a 90% CRUD application.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anemic_domain_model

Comment: If you started the Domain design 'forgetting'the the perssitence exists and you still ended up with 90% data strcutures, it's a strong possibility that you don't have a Domain OR if you know that there really are business concepts and processes that can be modelled, it's a strong smell of procedural code. Btw, DDD as its core just means: design the application according to the business process, not according to db structure. Entities, Aggregates and other fancy words are just details.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The percentage of domain services is not a useful metric of the quality of a domain model.

But "pure data structures with no behavior" are **[code smells](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anemic_domain_model), if you need a domain model**.

Now, you need a domain model if the business handled by your application is so complex that you need a domain expert to understand it. There are very few applications that requires DDD (Evans once stated just 5%), but they are often high budget ones. Such budgets come from two considerations: the **high complexity** of the business and the **competitive advantage** that the stakeholder obtains from them.

Even the percentage of the domain classes over the full project is not a useful metric: for example, in a CQRS application you will have a number of DTOs, but still you can have a good domain model that recieves commands. Moreover, it's fine to have a 90% CRUD application that, **in a well bounded operative context**, requires a domain model to enforce complex business invariants.

However, if you don't need a domain expert, you probably don't need a domain model.

If so, remember that **Buzzwords Driven Development** is very expensive.
You should not "try" to use DDD [if you don't really need it](http://www.slideshare.net/giacomotesio/epicnet-processes-patterns-and-architectures).

Comment: Well written answer, and regarding this exact phrase "Evans once stated just 5%", can you provide a reliable source. Plus if i don't use a domain model then what technique do you use for building the application. Do you go the old route of building the db first or is there another technique i don't know about. I am very interested in a technique suitable for CRUD applications. Another thing, if i don't go with a domain model and the project evolved to an unmanageable degree, wouldn't i be forced to fall back to a domain model again, sorry for the long comment full of questions ?

Comment: As for the Evans quote, I can't find that video anymore, sorry. As for the way to go, **the simplest possible thing that could possibly work** (I choose DDD only when it is the simplest method that can work): sometimes it's data driven, some times data are not that relevant (math engines, games and so on...). As for project evolution: business complexity guides the adoption of DDD, but no DDD does not means no architecture. Hire a good software architect and he will design the application properly for the evolutions that you can reasonably forecast.

Comment: i am interested in a little chat with you if that is possible, Thank you.

Comment: That's a good point about the bounded context. That other 10% may indeed require a domain.

Answer (score 3):

If the application is indeed 90% CRUD, then it does not have a Rich Domain. DDD is for Rich Domains and is probably not a good fit for the application. As the first comment notes, what you have is an Anemic Domain Model, which is considered an anti-pattern within the context of DDD, but is actually adequate for a majority applications. Eric Evans states in his book that DDD is not necessary most of the time.